# Swift - SharkORM ignore and encrypt property

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, dbaccess

I'm using [SharkORM](http://sharkorm.com/) to create a SQLite database but I have the following question.

How can I encrypt and ignore a property in sharkORM?

```
class Example: SRKObject {

    dynamic var birthdate : NSDate?
    dynamic var age : NSNumber?

}
```

I'm trying to calculate the age from the birthdate, and I don't want to have a column in the table for the age.

Also, my data should be secure so I want to encrypt the birthdate, how can this be implemented?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What is SharkORM? People might not know what you are asking about. It might help to provide a bit more information (such as a link to the library/framework in question) in such cases :) I was able to find what SharkORM is by looking it up, but not everybody might want to ...

Comment: @Fahim thanks for the advice, I added a link, but anyway the question is asked for those who already know it :)

Comment: Sure, but then you might be waiting for a long time and there are others who know nothing of SharkORM who might be able to help by just going through the docs - for example, the docs state "ignoreEntities Allows the developer to specify an array of child/related entities that will not be persisted when the parent object is commited." Perhaps that would be the place to start?

Comment: @Fahim good point and thank you for your help, actually I already went through the documentation and saw this, but there is no clear example and I couldn't know how to use it, and I don't know if this prevents a column from being created or just doesn't change its value when inserting a new record. That's why I provided an example, and it would be much appreciated if someone applies what I need on it. Thanks again for your help 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I might be wrong about `ignoreEntities` - that's not what you need. It appears that their documentation is not updated to reflect this but what you actually need is `ignoredProperties` :)

The actual Swift code you need to ignore a property on an object would look like this - I am using an example `Person` object to illustrate the code:

```
class Person: SRKObject {
    dynamic var name : String?
    dynamic var age : NSNumber?
    dynamic var payrollNumber : NSNumber?

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [Any] {
        return ["age"]
    }
}
```

Since I have not worked with SharkORM before, I tested the code to make sure that the above does indeed work correctly :)

On the subject of the implementation for `ignoredProperties`, generally, the unit tests for a project (if they exist) are a good place to start to see how to use a certain method. But strangely enough, SharkORM does not seem to implement any tests to see if `ignoredProperties` works as it should. Hopefully, somebody from the development team sees this and fixes this oversight :)

With regards to encrypting a specific property, I believe all you need to do is implement `encryptedPropertiesForClass`. Since the implementation will be similar to the above one for `ignoredProperties`, I will leave the actual implementation to you :)

Comment: done and done.  The next version has unit tests for those two functions.

Comment: @Adrian_H That's impressively fast updating :) Great work!

Comment: Ah, we have loads of stuff ready to go and not enough time to check it all in, test and produce releases.  But also, DBAccess (the predecessor) had most of the stuff documented from source using Doxygen, so it was just some straight forward plagiarism of things we had already created :)  We also had huge test scripts that we run, but are only slowly porting them to unit tests.

Comment: @Adrian_H I hadn't heard of SharkORM till today - I have my own lightweight (sort of) ORM that I use for most of my coding. But I was tempted to switch to SharKORM when I worked with it. So good luck with the coding and the unit tests - I know how much work goes into it!

Comment: Hi @Adrian_H I have managed to add the ignoredProperties successfully and the encrypted properties, but how can I decrypt the values when I read from the DB? or is it a one-way encryption? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Firas, it should be automatic.  When you access the property it should already be decrypted, are you not seeing that?

Comment: @Adrian_H Of curse I tried to read it :) but I'm getting this exception: 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SRKEncryptedObject doubleValue]

That's why I thought that there is a missing step, so could you please advise here?

Comment: @Firas, this might drag on a bit.  Do you want to email us, or carry this on in messages?  devs@db-access.org

Comment: @Adrian_H sure, I'll send an email with details in about 15 minutes, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Adrian_H Hi, I sent an email with the details but I didn't receive an answer till now, so I added the following new question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946134/sharkorm-encrypted-properties-issue-in-ios-swift-3

would you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> In Objective-C properties need to be implemented using @dynamic, this is to indicate to the ORM that it will control the fetching and setting of these values from the database, and in Swift the property is implemented as var dynamic

So, if you don't want `age` to be a column in the database, don't mark it as `dynamic`. Since you want age to be a calculated property, you would have something like:

```
var age: Int? {
    if let birthdate = birthdate {
        return // whole years from birthdate to today
    }
    return nil
}
```