# SharkORM Encrypted properties issue in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, dbaccess

I'm working on iOS project with DB, I am using SharkORM and integrate it to my project using cocoa pods, my project is built using Swift 3.

Everything is working perfectly, but now I need to add encrypted values to the DB and in order to test it I added a very simple code,

I created a "User" class in which I defined a "test" property, this property is of type Double:

```
dynamic var test: Double = 0;
```

I also added the following code to the class to define "test" as encrypted property:

```
override class func encryptedPropertiesForClass() -> [Any]! {
        return ["test"]
}
```

in order to read/write this property I did the following:

```
print(User.currentUser.test)
User.currentUser.test = 10
User.currentUser.commit()
print(User.currentUser.test)
```

Please note that current user is a singleton instance and it is being read from the DB. However, I'm getting the following exception:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SRKEncryptedObject doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Any idea why this is happening? thanks in advance.

Comment: I am currently debugging that scenario to see where a "double" goes.  Our tests only check Array, Dictionary,String atm.

Comment: @Adrian_H ok thanks :)

Comment: looks like a bug to me, i'll get it fixed in the next couple of days and a release out.  I wanted to change the way that code worked anyway.  But you can code your app to just assume that you set a double and get a double back and the encryption is transparent.  I am going to do it nearer the SQLite layer, and use the new Meta Tagging feature to tag the fact that it's encrypted onto the data type identifier.

Comment: Hi @Adrian_H, I appreciate your response, but can you tell me when do you expect this release to be published? thanks again.

Comment: I am planning for today if I can get all the tests to pass.  Might slip to tomorrow, but I hope not.

Comment: @Adrian_H hi, just checking, is the fix released or not yet, thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: No, I was literally just trying to work out why the tests are failing.  I've finished the coding and i'm trying to debug why encrypted objects are coming out as blobs and not their original type.  I have not forgotten about it, and it is holding up other releases and work too so it is my priority.

Comment: Ok, sorry again for keep asking but this was added to my schedule and I think I'm gonna delay it to later, thanks again, and your support is much appreciated.

Comment: @Adrian_H hello again Adrian, I need your help here please:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166988/ios-swift-import-data-from-sql-file-to-existing-sqlite-database thanks.