# iOS Swift import data from .sql file to existing SQLite database

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, dbaccess

I'm using SharkORM in my iOS Swift 3 app, what I'm trying to do is to import data to my SQLite database from a SQL script file, using the function:

```
SharkORM.rawQuery("INSERT INTO `Unit` (Id,name,symbol) VALUES (1,'kg/m²','kg/m²')")
```

However, I'm not able to add any record to my "Unit" table because I'm always getting the following error:

```
unrecognized token: \"\'k/gm²\""
```

Anyone know why this could be happening? and if there is another way to import .sql file to my database even if not using SharkORM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you creating a new table, or new columns? or just adding new data to an existing table?

Comment: I'm just importing large data to existing tables

Comment: Do those values work when using Terminal command line and attempting to insert those data into a SQLite 3.x database? I wonder if there may be some character restrictions.